# The use of Repository and unit of work patterns (revisited) ... in EF Core with ASP.NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I was following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/advanced#repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns) for EF Core with ASP.NET Core. The interesting thing is that this article states that 'the use of Repository and unit of work patterns is not always the best choice for applications that use EF', but in the tutorial of EF 5 the use of repository and unit of work patterns still is promoted even with a seperate tutorial part.

Reading  [old articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749153/why-use-repository-pattern-or-please-explain-it-to-me) on stackoverflow it is reported that the reasons one would apply it is mainly for testing (dependency injection).

Reading further in the turial it is mentioned that 'The Entity Framework Core implements an in-memory database provider that can be used for testing'. I presume this is a new feature that was not there at the time of EF5. Does this mean that there is hardly any reason anymore to apply the use of repository and unit of work patterns in EF Core with ASP.NET Core?

Comment: `DbContext` is unit of work and `DbSet` is repository.  You can implement a more traditional version of these patterns around EF but you'll only end up with a bunch of wrapper classes.  And that should be a red flag for any developer.

Comment: @CoffeCold there is no need for the repository or UOW patterns when using Entity Framework, Chris Pratt answer is great advice, the EF context is an abstraction that works the Dependency Injection and swapping databases. Brad's advice is great as well you just end up with a bunch of wrapper classes hiding yourself from the great DB abstracting that EF is trying to do for you in the first place

Comment: @Brad: First part of your comment is correct, though I **strongly** disagree with the later part. EF Core is infrastructure and you shouldn't spread it all over your code as this causes all of your layers to depend on EF/EF Core which is... well bad too. It's basically a choice of clear layer separation or sacrificing some of EF/EF Core's ORM features

Answer (score 13):

There's many reasons and a long history for why there's so much confusion here. EF's `DbContext` used to not implement an interface, so it made mocking it difficult for testing purposes. However, that was corrected in EF 6, so since that time there's been absolutely no benefit, even for testing purposes, in using the repository/unit of work patterns.

EF Core is completely testable end-to-end and has an in-memory database provider as well now, which means you don't even need to mock it, though you very much can if you want.

Long and short, dump the repository and unit of work patterns. They've never been a good solution even when they had some use for testing, and since EF 6, they have been completely useless.

Now... let the flame war begin.

Comment: Is there any really *good* `DbContext` mocking solution for EF6 yet?  What I mean by "good", is one that mimics all the database behaviors, like identity columns, FK / PK constraints, and standard population of navigation properties.  I've seen (and implemented) a few options, but none of them hit everything.  I think Core has the in-memory provider, which does *all* of this, but Core still seems like it's a very long way from being a feature-for-feature replacement of EF6.

Comment: Actually, EF Core is actually pretty feature complete. 2.0 went a long way in adding the majority of lacking features. What's left is mostly covered by 2.1 (in preview). As far as mocking goes, EF does do a lot under the hood, so it's always a bear to mock, with or without an abstraction layer. However, the in memory provider is great and works perfectly for testing.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: You got InMemory Provider for integration testing, it InMemory DB isn't a relational DB, so it doesn't enforce indexes and uniques, FK/PK relationships etc. If you want something closer to relational database you have to use Sqlite in-memory mode for integration tests. This is as official recommendation as the [official docs go for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory)

Comment: @Tseng thanks for that information. I wasn't aware that InMemory lacked those features.

Comment: I wouldn't consider the in memory provider to be integration testing. That's sort of the whole point actually. An integration test should actually, you know, test the integration of the components your app is using, such as a SQL Server database, which the in memory provider is not one of. You'd never actually use it in a real world scenario.

Comment: Likewise, SQLite would not be a replacement for integration testing, unless you're actually using it in production. The fact that your app can integrate with SQLite tells you nothing about whether it will actually work if you're deploying to SQL Server.

Comment: @ChrisPratt How about the multi-layered design ( Core, Database, WebApi ) ? I would like to have the DBContext defined and used only in Repository implementations ( in DB Layer ). And let the WebApis use just the Repository interfaces.

Comment: The database layer is EF and EF is the database layer. If you choose to use an ORM like EF, you are choosing to use a third-party database layer. Writing your own around that is pointless.

Comment: Additionally, APIs should have bounded contexts. You don't necessarily need a separate database per API (though some would recommend that as well), but each API should have its own context with only what it cares about. If there's overlap, then you haven't properly subdivided your domain, and those shouldn't be separate APIs.